# Create a geojson feature collection with java 8 Stream

Tags: java, jackson, java-stream, geojson

This is the Function that i wrote to convert a List into a ObjectNode representing a geojson FeatureCollection.

```
public class ToObjectNodeFunction implements Function<List<JsonNode>, ObjectNode> {

    @Override
    public ObjectNode apply(List<JsonNode> list) {
        /*
         * toGeojson() method return an ObjectNode representing that particular geometry
         */
        List<ObjectNode> objectNodes = list.parallelStream()
                .map(jsonNode -> {
                    String id = jsonNode.get("id").asText();
                    JsonNode tags = jsonNode.get("tags");
                    switch (jsonNode.get("type").asText()) {
                        case "node":
                            return new Point(jsonNode.get("lat").asDouble(), jsonNode.get("lon").asDouble(), id, tags).toGeojson();
                        case "way":
                            ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
                            JsonNode nodeList = jsonNode.get("geometry");
                            for (int j = 0; j < nodeList.size(); j++) {
                                JsonNode wayNode = nodeList.get(j);
                                points.add(j, new Point(wayNode.get("lat").asDouble(), wayNode.get("lon").asDouble()));
                            }
                            if (Polygon.isPolygon(points, tags)) {
                                return new Polygon(points, id, tags).toGeojson();
                            } else {
                                return new LineString(points, id, tags).toGeojson();
                            }
                        default:
                            Iterator<JsonNode> iterator = jsonNode.get("members").getElements();
                            List<List<Point>> rings = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<Point> ring;
                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                JsonNode member = iterator.next();
                                JsonNode geometry = member.get("geometry");
                                ring = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int ringIndex = 0; ringIndex < geometry.size(); ringIndex++) {
                                    JsonNode coordinates = geometry.get(ringIndex);
                                    ring.add(new Point(coordinates.get("lat").asDouble(), coordinates.get("lon").asDouble()));
                                }
                                rings.add(ring);
                            }
                            return new Multipolygon(Polygon.buildPolygons(rings), id, tags).toGeojson();
                    }
                })
                .collect(toList());

        ObjectNode featureCollection = NewFeatureCollection.createNewFeatureCollection();
        ArrayNode features = featureCollection.putArray("features");
        objectNodes.stream().forEach((objectNode) -> features.add(objectNode));

        return featureCollection;
    }
}
```

This method should be as fast as possible and I wonder if there is a better way to achieve the result. Particularly, I would like to avoid having to create a list of ObjectNode and then have to iterate to create an ObjectNode representing the feature collection. How can i create the feature collection directly?

Comment: I bet, not using a parallel stream will improve the performance. Besides that, consider reducing the code duplication. And instead of writing things like `objectNodes.stream().forEach((objectNode) -> features.add(objectNode));` you may simply write `features.addAll(objectNodes));`. Just as starting points…

Comment: Why a simple stream would be better than a parallelStream? I read many times this thing, but i don't get the reason behind it. I mean, i nead to process indipendent heavy tasks, X cores are not better than one? Features.addAll(objectNodes) doesn't work, it just works with a collection of JsonNode, not with a collection of ObjectNode.

Comment: If your tasks are really heavy or the list is large enough, you might get a benefit from parallel processing, but this code doesn’t look like this is the case. If you can’t use `addAll`, you should update the library, I’ve seen this invariant method declaration in [2.0.0](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)), but a covariant parameter in [2.6.0](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-)…